# how can I add a object into a realm list at a certain place in the list (IOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm

`var projects: Results<ProjectsModel>?`

Is it possible to insert an object into a Results list at a certain position?

I am trying to drag and drop cells in a collection view and I need to insert the item being dragged into the collection view.

projects.insert is not an option.

Comment: Please share your code snippet.

Comment: You could use the insert method: list.insert(object, at: index) or you could use the swap method if you want to swapAt two objects, which might be more suitable for a drag and drop situation: list.swapAt(index0, index1).

Comment: The way to handle this use case is to add a `position` property to your `ProjectsModel` object and sort your results by that field. That will allow you to reorder your results based on user interaction.

Comment: Unsorted Realm Results objects do not maintain ordering. From the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sorting) *Note that the order of Results is only guaranteed to stay consistent when the query is sorted*. However, if your filter includes a sort clause then it will maintain ordering. That being said, if you store an object in Realm and it fits the criteria of the Results filter and sort, it will automatically be added and sorted into the correct position automatically. You will need to use notifications to watch for that event so you know when to update your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsorted Realm Results objects do not maintain ordering.

From the docs

> Note that the order of Results is only guaranteed to stay consistent
>   when the query is sorted.

However, if your filter includes a sort clause then it will maintain ordering.

That being said, if you store an object in Realm and it fits the criteria of the Results filter and sort, it will automatically be added and sorted into the correct position automatically.

In other words, suppose your results object is sorted by a string property

```
class LetterObject: Object {
   @objc dynamic var letter = ""
}

let aLetter = LetterObject()
aLetter.letter = "a"

let cLetter = LetterObject()
cLetter.letter = "c"

let dLetter = LetterObject()
dLetter.letter = "d"
```

and then populate a class var that holds the letters; a, c, d sorted by the .letter property.

```
self.letterResults = realm.objects(LetterObject.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "letter")
```

then we add another letter object to Realm; b

```
let bLetter = LetterObject()
bLetter.letter = "b"

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(bLetter)
}
```

the self.letterResults will automatically be updated to include that letter; a, b, c, d and sorted.

You will need to use [notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) to watch for that event so you know when to update your UI.